# Make if in PHP infinite

Tags: php, controller, opencart

I need some help with php code.
I have this code in my controller/product/product.php (opencart 1.5.6):

```
            $rsNext     = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id+1);
            $rsNext2    = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id+2);
            $rsNext3    = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id+3);
            $rsLast     = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id-1);
            $rsLast2    = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id-2);
            $rsLast3    = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id-3);
            if($rsNext):
                $this->data['next_url'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' .  $rsNext['product_id']);
                $this->data['next_text']= $rsNext['name']." &gt;&gt;";

            elseif($rsNext2):
                $this->data['next_url'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' .  $rsNext2['product_id']);
                $this->data['next_text']= $rsNext2['name']." &gt;&gt;";

            elseif($rsNext3):
                $this->data['next_url'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' .  $rsNext3['product_id']);
                $this->data['next_text']= $rsNext3['name']." &gt;&gt;";
            else:
                $this->data['next_url'] = '';
                $this->data['next_text']= '';
            endif;

            if($rsLast):
                $this->data['prev_url'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' .  $rsLast['product_id']);
                $this->data['prev_text']= "&lt;&lt; ".$rsLast['name'];

            elseif($rsLast2):
                $this->data['prev_url'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' .  $rsLast2['product_id']);
                $this->data['prev_text']= "&lt;&lt; ".$rsLast2['name'];

            elseif($rsLast3):
                $this->data['prev_url'] = $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' .  $rsLast3['product_id']);
                $this->data['prev_text']= "&lt;&lt; ".$rsLast3['name'];
            else:
                $this->data['prev_url'] = '';
                $this->data['prev_text']= null;
            endif;
```

How i could make this infinite, because are situations where need product_id+15 for example or more.
Thanks!

Comment: Infinite? That would take an infinite amount of time for the code to execute. How about you just use a loop?

Comment: This is what I want but how I make loop ? If I will make loop this will affect my loadspeed ?

Comment: Use while or foreach  to make a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$product_id` is an integer, you can make a loop like so:

```
$from = $product_id -10;
$to = $product_id + 10;

for($i = $from; $i<$to; $i++){
  echo $i;
}
```

Will it affect your load speed, yes. If you would ask by how much, a minimum. Maybe a few microseconds. Need more examples? Take a look at this very easily constructed [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+loop+integer) query.

Answer (score 0):

Make a loopp using foreach

basic example using if inside foreach loop

```
$number = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($number as $num){
    if($num > 5){
        echo '<li>Greater than - '.$num.'</li>';
    }else{
        echo '<li>less than - '.$num.'</li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: `foreach` on 6 variables, whome all integers? It does not seem logical ~Vulcan